# Many-to-one multiplicity when there's an association of a class with two classes

Tags: uml, class-diagram

CONTEXT: I have an abstract class ***Student***. From this class I derive three concrete classes **SchoolStudent, UnderGradStudent**, **PostGradStudent**. I have another class **Vehicle**. A school student must **NOT** drive a vehicle however, an undergrad or a postgrad student **may or may not** drive a vehicle.But every vehicle must be driven by somebody hence the **Vehicle** class has a reference to a student.

PROBLEM: I have association between classes **UnderGradStudent & Vehicle** and another association between **PostGradStudent & Vehicle**. However, I am a little confused about the multiplicity.

As I understand the problem, the UML class diagram should look something like this:[image]

However, I suspect the above diagram suggests that each **Vehicle** will have one **UnderGradStudent** as well as one **PostGradStudent**.

Is the above diagram correct as to what I want to model corresponding to the context?

Answer (score 2):

As you've drawn this UML diagram, it *implies* (but does not say correctly) that a `Vehicle` must be driven by both one `UnderGradStudent` and one `PostGradStudent`. It also implies that an `UnderGradStudent` can drive any number of `Vehicle`s and a `PostGradStudent` can drive any number of `Vehicle`s (at the same time). I don't think that's what you intended. The reason I say "implies" is that you have overlaid two associations on one end. Last I checked, that is invalid UML.

I think you wanted to say that a `Vehicle` may be driven by up to one `Undergrad Student` or `Postgrad Student`. To say that, I recommend the following model:

[image: Corrected Diagram]

What this says is:

- A valid instance of `Student` must be one of `School Student`, `Undergrad Student`, or `Postgrad Student` (and not multiply classified)
- A valid instance of `Allowed Driver` must be one of `Undergrad Student` or `Postgrad Student` (and not multiply classified)
- A `Vehicle` can be driven by up to one `Allowed Driver` (at a time)
- An `Allowed Driver` drives up to one `Vehicle` (at a time)

This describes a valid situation at any point in time, which is really useful. Think of it as a way to evaluate the validity of any frame in a movie.

If you need to record all the drivers of every vehicle *ever*, you would need to make many changes. A `Person` actually plays the role of a `Student` (among other roles, usually), and that role can change over time. You would need to record the start and end time of every role change and the start and end time of every driver / vehicle change. Think of this as recording all the frames in a movie, but without the ability to express the validity of any given frame in the movie. You lose that ability when you relax multiplicities.

You can get the benefits of the "single frame" and the "whole movie" approach by combining *all* of the associations I mentioned.

Comment: This will solve the problem but uses multiple inheritance (MI). Probably a matter of taste, but MI  from my POV is just a technical construct and nothing from reality. E.g. an amphi-car does not inherit from ship and car one might think. It's a class of its own. MI must always be used with care.

Comment: This is an analysis model of the semantics. Multiple inheritance is quite common in OOA and knowledge representation. It would also be equivalent to place Allowed Driver below Student if you have a target language that is incompatible with MI, such as Java.

Comment: @JimL. Thanks you for the reply. However, my target language is Java which does not support MI. Also, I am unable to gather what you are trying to say in your comment about placing the "AllowedDriver" below Student in case . It would be really helpful if you can elaborate a bit.

Comment: I'll try to explain in text. Snip the generalization lines from undergrad and postgrad to student and make a generalization line from allowed driver to student, then rearrange all the subclasses to make them hierarchical.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem will easily be solved by using a 0..1 multiplicity near the `*Student` classes from the `Vehicle`. This will tell the reader that both are allowed to have a related optional vehicle. To avoid both using the same car you need to attach a constraint like this:

[image]

Alternatively you can do it the following way:

[image]

I'm not good in writing OCL but you could formalize the constraint as well.

Comment: Please see my edit. Your own diagram suggested multiple cars allowed for a drive. Changed that according to your comment.